# Can vanilla NN model a moving Average (MA) process?

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, arima, tensorflow, keras

Let say I simulate an AR(1) process. We can easily model the data with a vanilla NN with a single neuron as it is about finding the linear relationship between $y$ and $y_{t-1}$.

Now, how about a MA(1)? Can a vanilla NN model that MA process? And if not why (w.r.t universal approximation theorem) and what kind of structure would you need?

Comment: With an MA(1), there's a linear relationship between $y_t$ and the previous error term so I imagine you can do a similar thing except that the coefficient is the coefficient of the previous error, $\epsilon_{t-1}$. Note that MA(1) is $y_t = \theta \times \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$.

Comment: If you give $\epsilon_{t-1}$ as feature as well, why not.

Comment: The thing is that errors terms are not observed values.

Comment: You could use a simple one node NN to get those error terms and then feed those into more layers to provide the actual forecast.  So like a 2 stage NN.

Comment: @Junior Hechinger: The estimates of error terms are available. $\epsilon_{t-1}$ is the just the error from the previous  prediction,. So, $\hat{\epsilon}_{t-1} = \hat{y}_{t-1}  - \theta \hat{\epsilon}_{t-2}$ and so on and so forth.